# Correct answer for "Jumping into C++" chapter 13, quiz 3?

Tags: c++

Which of the following gives the memory address of a variable pointed to by pointer p_a?

A. p_a;

B. *p_a;

C. &p_a;

D. address( p_a );

So I'm reading this book called "Jumping into C++" and this quiz came up after one chapter. When I checked the right answer from the book it showed that the correct answer was **C. &p_a;**. Wouldn't &p_a just give the memory address of a pointer variable p_a instead of memory address of variable it is pointing to?

Now I'd say that this is not the correct answer, but I can't be sure. After all I'm still a beginner so I don't dare to start questioning answers in the book just yet. I'd say that the correct answer is A. Tell me, is there a mistake in the answers or what?

Comment: am loving the voting history: -1, -1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p_a` is a pointer pointing to a variable. That is, it yields the *address* of that variable.

`*p_a` is the value of the variable.

`&p_a` is the address of the pointer (pointers have memory locations too).

`address( p_a )` is some nonsense.

Hence the answer is **A** and the book is incorrect. **Burn it**.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do it. **It's digital.**

Comment: Though `address( p_ a)` is nonsense, C++11 introduced `std::addressof` in order to get the address of objects that have overloaded the unary `&` operator. So it's two characters away from being legit!

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am totally misunderstanding the question, you are right and the book is wrong. `p_a` is a pointer, meaning it is the address of the variable it points to.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the exact wording of the question, then you're right: the answer is A.

- `p_a` is the value of the pointer, which is the address of the object it points to
- `*p_a` dereferences the pointer, giving the object it points to
- `&p_a` gives the address of the pointer, not the object
- `address(p_a)` calls a function called `address`, if one exists - there's no way to know what that function might return.

(There is a library function, `std::addressof(p_a)`, which gives the address of `p_a`, like `&p_a` does, even if it's an evil type that changes the meaning of `&`. But that's not relevant here.)

Answer (score 0):

pointers are used to contain addresses of other objects. So the value of an initialized pointer is  address of an object.  So the correct answer will be the answer marked as A. that is p_a.